# How to join multiple SQL tables and get counts of each

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate

I need a T-SQL query that can join multiple tables but also returns counts from each. I know how to do each part separately but can not get them working together.

Given this SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [House] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Price] DECIMAL (5, 2) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [Floor] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [HouseId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Floor_HouseId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([HouseId]) REFERENCES [House] ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Room] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FloorId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Type] VARCHAR,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Room_FloorId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([FloorId]) REFERENCES [Floor] ([Id])
);
```

I need a SQL query that will return a single list with the following information, I understand the query will be likely be messy.

- [House].[Id]
- [House].[Price]
- [FloorCount] - The total number of floors in each house
- [RoomCount] - The total number of rooms in each house
- [BedroomCount] - The number of rooms in the house where [Type] = 'Bedroom'

Comment: what have tried so far? which sql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way but I solved it by grouping by the house id and just using the max function to get the price. There are multiple rows, all with the same price but I just needed to get one of them.

```
SELECT [House].[Id],
       MAX([House].[Price]),
       COUNT(distinct [Floor].[Id]) AS [FloorCount],
       COUNT(distinct [Room].[Id]) as [TotalRoomCount],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Bedroom' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BedroomCount]
FROM [House]
LEFT JOIN [Floor] ON [Floor].[HouseId] = [House].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Room] on [Room].[FloorId] = [Floor].[Id]
GROUP BY [House].[Id];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregation query.  It does not seem particularly complicated:

```
select f.houseid,
       count(distinct f.id) as numfloors,
       count(*) as numrooms,
       sum(case when type = 'bedroom' then 1 else 0 end) as numbedrooms
from floor f join
     room r
     on f.id = r.floorid
group by f.houseid;
```